# WiFi Goes Down When Computer Sleeps

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, sleep

This is a bit of an odd one.

Every time my roommate puts his computer to sleep (an HP laptop with Windows 7), the WiFi goes out for a minute or two. It used to happen with my desktop, too, an older Dell with a WiFi card, but it doesn't seem to trigger it any more.

The router is a Trendnet TEW-639GR with up-to-date firmware.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: From the command prompt: what happen when you run 'ipconfig /all' from another computer when his is connected to the network vs. when it's off? Can you run and compare 'ipconfig /all' between his computer and the other computer when his is connected to the network vs. not connected? My guess is that it's something to do with dhcp settings.

Comment: I don't believe there is any difference.